# Import "django.db.models" could not be resolved from source / py manage.py makemigrations No changes detected

Tags: python, django, visual-studio-code, django-models

I am working on a project using django and I am using Visual Studio Code software.

In my 'store' directory i have a python package called 'tiendaonline' and the app called "gestionpedidos" where I am trying to create a a Table (DDBB)

The problem i am getting is that I cannot create table because when I try to run  "py manage.py makemigrations" I can see the msg "No changes detected". Also I can see in the window called problems this msg: "  Import "django.db.models" could not be resolved from source  "

My setting.py is like this:

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'gestionpedidos',
]
```

and my model is this:

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class Pedidos(models.Model):
    numero = models.IntegerField(max_length=100 )
    fecha = models.DateField(max_length=300 )
    entregado = models.BooleanField() 

class Clientes(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30 )
    direc = models.CharField(max_length=50 )
    Email = models.EmailField() 
    Tel = models.EmailField() 

class Articulos(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100 )
    seccion = models.CharField(max_length=300 )
    price = models.IntegerField()
```

I don't know what is happening. It could give me an adress of migration like "0001_init" but is not running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

restart your vs code first and then activate your virtual environment if you are using. do again makemigrations and migrate if still no changes detected then delete recent migration and do it again

Comment: Restart the VS Code was the solution! Thank you so much!!

Answer (score 1):

If django is not detecting the changes do this
`py manage.py makemigrations gestionpedidos` to look for changes in that app only. I'm not sure why but this has worked for me countless times in the past.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is the answer when I write the name of the app:  PS C:\Users\Cache\Desktop\python\tiendaonline> py manage.py makemigrations gestionpedidos
No changes detected in app 'gestionpedidos'

Answer (score 1):

Go to view > command Palette > Python: select interpreter > { select the one where Django is installed }. This worked for me .